# $\int_{100}^{200} \frac{1}{ 8 + b\sqrt{1-\frac{(x-100)^2}{100^2} } + b\sqrt{1-\frac{(x-200)^2}{100^2} } } dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{100}^{200} \frac{1}{ 8  +  b\sqrt{1-\frac{(x-100)^2}{100^2} }  +  b\sqrt{1-\frac{(x-200)^2}{100^2} } } dx$

I tried this in Mathematica but got the same thing as solution. By considering "b" = 1, I got solution as something big with lot of imaginary terms. I am expecting that this integration could give me a function in terms of "b".

Comment: Do you really want to have a negative value within the square roots (as you do)?  I suspect you've set up your equation wrong, guaranteeing you get imaginary integrand values.  Recheck.

Comment: @vishal, I tried to edit you script, please approve it if it is correct or edit it again.

Comment: I really don't understand what you have written